# Adding a chat app to an existing Django application on Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, websocket, chat

I have a fairly large Django project running on Heroku. I'm trying to add a chat app to the project but as far as I can tell, Heroku does not allow multiple ports to be used for an added websocket. I have also tried to use Django channels, but I haven't found any tutorials on adding channels to an existing project, so I have struggled with that as well. I'm trying to avoid making a new Heroku application to solve this. What are my options for adding a websocket to an existing Django application that would run on Heroku?